# How to pass out a .net reference in a LabVIEW VI as an output?

Tags: labview

I created a small LabVIEW VI which prompts for some database connection details and then returns a .net object which has methods to access data stored in the database. This works fine so far. But now I want to use this as a Sub-VI and thus I need to pass out the created database connector object as an output.

Everything I found when searching was to hook up an output control (text or numeric) to the "wiring panel" (I don't know what the English name for this is, in my German version it is called "Anschlussfeld"), but obviously, this only works for text, numbers and the like.

Is it only possible to output these types, or can I also output .net references, and if so, how do I do this?

Comment: >... "but obviously, this only works for text, numbers and the like"   
   
Why would you think that? As shown below, you can connect an indicator of any data type to the connector pane to use it as an output.  
  
You can also just right click pretty much any node with a data type on the block diagram and create a matching indicator from the context menu.

Comment: I just missed that I could change a .net refnum to output and wire it up to the "Anschlussfeld"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `.NET Refnum` control, on the *Controls » Ref Num* [palette](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/types_of_refnum_controls/).

For example, open the **Task Monitor Using .NET Objects** example VI: from the *Help* menu, select *Find Examples*, then double-click *Communicating with External Applications*, and then double-click on *.NET*. Change one of the constructor nodes into a subVI and inspect the new VI's front panel and connector pane.

Here's an illustration:

[image]

Comment: That is one nice image.  I love it.